# Elastic SIEM + Google Cloud Platform

Tags: elasticsearch, google-cloud-platform, logstash

i would like to analyze gcp logs with Elastic SIEM.
These logs are inserted into an index of Elasticsearch using Logstash.
Analyzing them with elastic siem I don't get any hits, is this due to their structure?
Can you tell me what kind of filter to use so that everything works?
Here is an example of log:

```
{
  "protoPayload": {
    "authorizationInfo": [
      {
        "granted": true,
        "permission": "logging.sinks.list",
        "resource": "projects/myfirstproject-xxxx",
        "resourceAttributes": {
          "name": "projects/myfirstproject-xxxx",
          "service": "logging.googleapis.com"
        }
      }
    ],
    "request": {
      "parent": "projects/myfirstproject-xxxx",
      "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.logging.v2.ListSinksRequest",
      "pageSize": 100
    },
    "resourceName": "projects/myfirstproject-xxxx",
    "methodName": "google.logging.v2.ConfigServiceV2.ListSinks",
    "serviceName": "logging.googleapis.com",
    "requestMetadata": {
      "requestAttributes": {
        "time": "2021-01-13T18:27:03.019679173Z"
      },
      "callerIp": "37.182.191.89",
      "callerSuppliedUserAgent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.141 Safari/537.36,gzip(gfe),gzip(gfe)"
    },
    "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog",
    "authenticationInfo": {
      "principalEmail": "xxx"
    }
  },
  "logName": "projects/myfirstproject-xxxx/logs/cloudaudit.googleapis.com%2Fdata_access",
  "resource": {
    "type": "logging_sink",
    "labels": {
      "name": "",
      "project_id": "myfirstproject-xxxx",
      "destination": ""
    }
  },
  "receiveTimestamp": "2021-01-13T18:27:03.947934153Z",
  "timestamp": "2021-01-13T18:27:03.012844051Z",
  "@version": "1",
  "severity": "INFO",
  "@timestamp": "2021-01-13T19:58:51.272Z",
  "messageId": "1915086580392352",
  "insertId": "bxr3dbc7x4",
  "_index": "logstash-2021.01.13",
  "_type": "_doc",
  "_id": "HWNU_XYBn2IF1Ov-WnDH",
  "_score": 1,
  "fields": {
    "@version": [
      "1"
    ],
    "insertId": {
      "keyword": [
        "bxr3dbc7x4"
      ]
    },
    "@timestamp": [
      "2021-01-13T19:58:51.272Z"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Don't you need a service account key in order to get logs? Are you collecting GCP logs with Beats? And send them to Logstash?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
I don't use any beats, the logs are taken from gcp and insert to elasticserach using only Logstash.
The logs are inserted correctly in the index but I cannot analyze them with Elastic SIEM.

Comment: The Elastic SIEM only works with fields that follow the [Elastic Common Schema](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/ecs/current/index.html), since you are using logstash you would need to rename every field to fit one of the categories, which is a lot of work to do. You could try to use the [google cloud module](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/7.x/filebeat-module-gcp.html) from filebeat to collect your logs since it will take care of the parsing and naming of the fields.

Comment: I was hoping that some users had created special filters to be included in logstash